# crud delete not working anymore

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i used the crud delete method and it works for me, but when i tried it with a different database and table it keeps saying "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()"

this is my "vacature-verwijderen.php" where you should be able to delete it

```
            <div>
            <table id="tabel">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Functie</th>
                  <th>Omschrijving</th>
                  <th>Salaris</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
              <?php
               include 'database.php';
               $pdo = Database::connect();
               $sql = 'SELECT * FROM vacature ORDER BY id DESC';
               foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
                        echo '<tr>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['functie'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['omschrijving'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td>'. $row['salaris'] . '</td>';
                        echo '<td width=250>';
                        echo '<a class="button  " href="update.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Update</a>';
                        echo ' ';
                        echo '<a class="button" href="delete.php?id='.$row['id'].'">Delete</a>';
                        echo '</td>';
                        echo '</tr>';
                        }
               Database::disconnect();
              ?>
              </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then when you click delete you go to "delete.php" which looks like this

```
<?php
require 'database.php';
$id = 0;

if ( !empty($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
}

if ( !empty($_POST)) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sql = "DELETE FROM vacature  WHERE id = ?";
    $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute(array($id));
    Database::disconnect();
    header("Location: vacature-verwijderen.php");

}
?>
```

i don't know what is wrong since it used to work, also my database table looks like this

[image: screen]

Comment: Please look for error messages. From your screenshot: you want to delete by *id*. But there is no column with name *id*

Comment: @BenRoob my god, i'm so sorry, i literally couldn't figure out what it was but that's it. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($pdo->query($sql) as $row) {
```

That's what is wrong. `$pdo->query($sql)` already returns your `$row`.

Use a while instead so that it do the query and returns you the new row as long as there is data to fetch :

```
while ($row = $pdo->query($sql)) {
```

Also :

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM vacature  WHERE id = ?";
```

The table you provided doesn't contain any field named *id*, although there is one named *vacature_id*. You might want to change that too :

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM vacature  WHERE vacature_id = ?";
```

Don't hesitate to come back if it doesn't solve your issue.